# Pyspark distribute dependencies with .so files in cluster with no internet

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pythonpath, egg

I would like to use Pyspark and distribute a set of dependencies in a cluster with no internet access. I tried `pip install -t dependencies -r requirements.txt` and then zipped the dependencies folder. I passed the zip as `spark.submit.pyFiles` and it works, **except when the module has .so files inside** (e.g. numpy). In that case I am getting [this error](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15584#issuecomment-610009721). I get exactly the same error if I open a local fresh python console after pointing PYTHONPATH to the zip file: looks like it can find the python packages except for the .so files, so it is not really related to pyspark but the general python mechanism of package loading from a zip file. If I unzip the file and point PYTHONPATH to the unzipped folder, everything works well.

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756235/python-import-error-with-zip/36757635#36757635) so I tried egg files instead, with the same result: after pip install into the dependencies target folder, I create a single egg file as mentioned there using setuptools, by first creating a setup.py in the dependencies folder, like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "dependencies",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages()
)
```

and then calling `python setup.py bdist_egg`. I distribute the resulting .egg file in the pyFiles argument but same error. I tried creating a `native_libs.txt` file where I manually write the path of the .so files there are inside the numpy/core subfolder, but seems to have no effect when I run the bdist command: the .so are not copied into the numpy subfolder of the egg, so I manually copied them there, but no success. Pointed PYTHONPATH to the egg file but got exactly the same error.

My python version is 3.7.6 when I create the egg, and 3.7.7 in the Spark workers but I'm almost sure this is not causing the problem.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Maybe using another spark argument different than pyFiles?

Thanks

Note: this [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6764) is related to this question as well.